# hide and display elements using a dropdown menu

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I was wondering if its possible to hide and display different elements by using a dropdown menu. Currently i have this code for my menu:

```
<select id="productSel" onChange="OnSelectedIndexChange()">
        <option value="0">Value 0</option>
        <option value="1">Value 1</option>
        <option value="2">Value 2</option>
</select>
```

and this for my javascript:

```
<script>
            function OnSelectedIndexChange() {
                if (document.getElementById('productSel').value == "0"){
                document.getElementById("Option1").style.display = "block";
                document.getElementById("Option2").style.display = "none";
                document.getElementById("Option3").style.display = "none";
                }
            };
        </script>
        <script>
            function OnSelectedIndexChange() {
                if (document.getElementById('productSel').value == "1"){
                document.getElementById("Option1").style.display = "none";
                document.getElementById("Option2").style.display = "block";
                document.getElementById("Option3").style.display = "none";
                }
            };
        </script>
        <script>
            function OnSelectedIndexChange() {
                if (document.getElementById('productSel').value == "2"){
                document.getElementById("Option1").style.display = "none";
                document.getElementById("Option2").style.display = "none";
                document.getElementById("Option3").style.display = "block";
                }
            };
        </script>
```

and this is the area that needs to change:

```
<div id="Option1" style="display:none">
<p>Option1</p>
<p>Line 2</p>
```

theres 2 more divs just like that except with different Option numbers but for some reason it wont show the rest of my code past the closing div tag. Im having trouble because that code works, except it only works for the top option. so if theres 3 options, they start off as all invisible the way i wanted but when i pick an option from the menu, it wont display them. it will only display the third option and not the other 2. if theres 2 options it will only display the second option and not the first, even if i pick the first one. This is my first time asking on here so im sorry if i wasnt clear

Comment: Why three separate OnSelectedIndexChange() , it cud have been merged into one ...

Comment: i had tried several times but i messed it up each time. im new to javascript so i have a lot to learn

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dropdown box should be call 3 time events.Which you are created, so it last function call every time.You can change like this.

```
<script>
            function OnSelectedIndexChange() {
                if (document.getElementById('productSel').value == "0"){
                document.getElementById("Option1").style.display = "block";
                document.getElementById("Option2").style.display = "none";
                document.getElementById("Option3").style.display = "none";
                }

                else if (document.getElementById('productSel').value == "1"){
                document.getElementById("Option1").style.display = "none";
                document.getElementById("Option2").style.display = "block";
                document.getElementById("Option3").style.display = "none";
                }

                else if (document.getElementById('productSel').value == "2"){
                document.getElementById("Option1").style.display = "none";
                document.getElementById("Option2").style.display = "none";
                document.getElementById("Option3").style.display = "block";
                }
            };
        </script>
```

Comment: thank you! that worked perfectly! im very new to JS so i still have a lot to learn. i actually tried what you showed but i added an extra } to the end of each else if statement so that must have messed it up

Comment: this is my first time using this site, did i mark it? i pressed the big arrow

Answer (score 0):

You are replacing the function each time you redefine it. It will only execute the `value == "2"` version.

At the least, you need to put all of the conditions inside a single copy of the function.